# How to make moveable inputAccessoryView in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uisearchbar

i am now trying to create moveable `inputAccessoryView` for `UISearchBar` like following pic.

[image]

I can add `inputAccessoryView` top of the InputView,However my `inputAccessoryView` can't moveable.

How can i do it like above pic?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you create one UIView for the inputAccessoryView, then add other views to that, those added views should be moveable, no?

Comment: I don't understand what are you meaning?

Comment: You create a UIView of say 40 by 320. This will be the inputAccessoryView. Now add other views as subviews to that container view. You can animate or change the frame of the subviews. This appears to be what you want.

Comment: Could you please help me with some code :)?